# How can I loop through this array? And fill a carousel?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, carousel

Basically I have this array:

```
$videos = array('Aicw1LoHTmc' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-9.jpg', 
            'ZfIoMBo2yOw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-2.jpg', 
            'LGs6Jvb5jqM' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-3.jpg',
            'RMbgEc-s5Jw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-4.jpg', 
            'enKA9qeAO4A' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-5.jpg', 
            'lXBY5lPccfo' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-6.jpg', 
            'DSDmjjj1Fuw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-7.jpg');
```

the key is a youtube video ID (will be used in the href (query string) and the value is the path of the image that will be used for the carousel.

This is what my code for part of the carousel looks like :

```
<img alt="" src="../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="figcaption bg-base"></div>
    <div class="figcaption-btn">
    <a href="../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-1.jpg" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white theater"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Zoom</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> View</a>
    </div>
```

I want the source to be changed to the path within the array, likewise with the first href and then the last href will contain the videoID (the key of the array).

This is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
     $new = array();
     foreach($videos as $key => $value){
        $new[$key] = $value;
          if($key == $v){
            $offset = array_search($key, array_keys($new));
            array_splice($new, $offset, 1, array('../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-1.jpg'));
        }
    }
    $new = array_combine(str_replace("0","#",array_keys($new)), $new);      
}
    print_r($new);
```

```
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="wp-block inverse">
                                    <div class="figure">
                                    <?php foreach($new as $key => $value){ ?>
                                        <img alt="" src="<?php echo $value ?>" class="img-responsive">
                                        <div class="figcaption bg-base"></div>
                                        <div class="figcaption-btn">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $value ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white theater"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Zoom</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                                            <h2>Title1</h2>
                                            <small>Description1</small>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

However I don't know how to loop through this so that the first element is displayed in the first carousel image, and second element in the second carousel image and so on...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($array as $key => $value){ ?>
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $value; ?>" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="figcaption bg-base"></div>
    <div class="figcaption-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white theater"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Zoom</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> View</a>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

This may be what you're looking for. Given that you're ok with the format.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However I did try to loop through the array using a foreach however it makes the carousel much larger than just 8 images, around 30+ images.

Comment: Does the array have 30+ elements? If so, there's your answer. You could go crazy any limit the query to however many items you want and do it via ajax.

Comment: no the array has 7 elements, would ajax be better to use opposed to php ?

Comment: If the array has only 7 elements and you're getting 30+ images, there's something wrong with your code. I suggest updating your post so I can have a look at it. Ajax wouldn't be better or worse, it's a matter of the right tool. Stick with PHP for now. No point in making things more complicated.

Comment: I think the issue is that I have 8 elements to my carousel and (7 in my array) so when I echo $value / $ key on every element in my array it iterates through the entire loop for each element in the carousel.

Comment: That's most probably it.

Comment: I have just updated my post, but my current code displays the next / previous buttons for the carousel but no images at all now.

Comment: Replace the `$new` variable in  `<?php foreach($new as $key => $value){ ?>` with `$videos`. It should work ok.

Comment: ah i realized the issue i need to loop through and re-iterate the entire structure of the carousel, re-create the entire div that contains the image, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As per Video Array you may integrate this code to fill you carousel with using for each array. I will recommend you to use "foreach" loop instead of "for".

```
<?php
$videos = array('Aicw1LoHTmc' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-9.jpg',
'ZfIoMBo2yOw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-2.jpg',
'LGs6Jvb5jqM' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-3.jpg',
'RMbgEc-s5Jw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-4.jpg',
'enKA9qeAO4A' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-5.jpg',
'lXBY5lPccfo' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-6.jpg',
'DSDmjjj1Fuw' => '../v2assets/images/carousel/wk-img-7.jpg');

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($videos); echo '</pre>';

foreach ($videos as $id => $img_src) {
?>
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $img_src ?>" class="img-responsive">
<div class="figcaption bg-base"></div>
<div class="figcaption-btn">
<a href="<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white theater">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Zoom</a>
<a href="<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-b-white"> 
<i class="fa fa-link"></i> View</a>
</div>

<?php
}
```